# Handling nested dictionaries with python requests

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I recently got my first [Flask webapp](http://www.asosquery.com/) hosted, and built a relatively simple API around it. It's driven by a very large database full of open meteorological surface observations (more info on the `/about` page), and right now I'm able to query the API with the following sample code (a separate script written for testing):

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('http://www.asosquery.com/api/v1/stations?state=PA&lat={"gt": 39, "lt": 50}')
content = json.loads(r)
```

This returns JSON-encoded information regarding all [ASOS stations](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/ost/asostech.html) with a latitude greater than 39.00 N and less than 50.00 N. A SQLAlchemy query of the MySQL database is dynamically generated based on the arguments in the `GET` request.

However, I would like to be able to do something like this, following an example on the [requests package documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```
import requests # standard python requests package
import json

payload = {
    'state': 'PA',
    'lat': {
        'gt': 39,
        'lt': 50
    }
}

r = requests.get('http://www.asosquery.com/api/v1/stations', params=payload)
content = json.loads(r)
```

This exercise fails each time. In the Flask route `/api/v1/stations`, I've tried printing the request made to the server like this:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/api/v1/stations', methods=['GET'])
def get_stations():
    print(request)
    print(request.args)
    # -- do the query stuff here -- #
    return jsonify(query_results)
```

But, the output (prior to a raised error) is not as I expected it to be:

```
# print(request) prints:
<Request 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/stations?lat=lt&lat=gt&state=PA' [GET]>
# print(request.args) prints:
ImmutableMultiDict([('lat', 'lt'), ('lat', 'gt'), ('state', 'PA')])
```

I've tried encoding the `payload` as JSON with the following:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.asosquery.com/api/v1/stations', params=json.dumps(payload), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

but execution of that code prints the following in from the flask route:

```
# print(request) prints:
<Request 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/stations?{"state": "PA", "lat": {"gt": 39, "lt": 50}}' [GET]>
# print(request.args) prints:
ImmutableMultiDict([('{"state": "PA", "lat": {"gt": 39, "lt": 50}}', '')])
```

At the moment, the query fails to execute due to the unexpected nature of the argument formatting.

Anybody know a good workaround? Am I handling the greater-than, less-than functionality in the best way possible?

Thank you in advance to all who offer some insight.

Comment: Why don't you use POST method and put the json payload in the request body?

Comment: To be honest, I was under the impression that a `GET` request was the right protocol for simple select queries. Thought `POST` was more suited for adding data to the DB. @Jean Rostan made a similar comment in the answer below. I'm going to have to think about revising

Answer (score 0):

Workaround would be not to nest the dictionary:

```
payload = {
    'state': 'PA',
    'lat': "{'gt': 39,'lt': 50}"
}
```

It does work, but it's quite ugly.

Comment: Yeah, that's the crux of it. I'm trying to build something that's intuitive, and unfortunately that workaround doesn't seem much more so than what I've got currently. Do you know if a nested dictionary is the best way to do greater-than and less-than operations?

Comment: @nat5142 I mean, there's no way requests is supposed to know that your query param is a string and not a dic unless you tell him. If you're building a custom API, I would use a POST with a body payload instead of query params, which would allow for proper JSON filters

Comment: Really? You would use POST? Hm, I guess my understanding of REST could use a boost. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @nat5142 it's how we do it at work. I'm not saying it's the way to go, but at least, it works and allows for clean queries.